# How to get Watson Assistant to response correctly

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

First of all, sorry for language errors, I'm Brazilian.

I'm trying to create a Watson chatbot and I'm running into this issue.

I'm making chatbot that's take orders.

At the end, the bot responses 'Thank you! You asked for a ["hot dog","big coke","fries"].'

How can i get a response like 'Thank you! You asked for a hot dog, a big coke and fries.'?

**Additional information:**

the JSON for take the order:

```
{
  "context": {
    "menu": "@menu.values"
  }
}
```

I made the response like this:

> Thank you! You asked for a $menu.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, the $menu is a JSON array. Referring just to its values, gives the printed values as shown by you. Take a look at the Watson Assistant expressions for handling JSON data, especially [JSONArray.join](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-join).

It combines the values of an array into a single string. Something like this should work.

```
Thank you! You asked for <? $menu.join(', ') ?>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! I appreciate for the reading, will be very useful.